# Obtaining frame pointer in C

Tags: c, assembly, x86

I'm trying to get the FP in my C program, I tried two different ways, but they both differ from what I get when I run GDB.

The first way I tried, I made a protocol function in C for the Assembly function:

```
int* getEbp();
```

and my code looks like this:

```
int* ebp = getEbp(); 
printf("ebp: %08x\n", ebp); // value i get here is 0xbfe2db58

while( esp <= ebp )       
    esp -= 4;

printf( "ebp: %08x, esp" ); //value i get here is 0xbfe2daec
```

My assembly code

```
getEbp:
    movl %ebp, %eax
    ret
```

I tried making the prototype function to just return an int, but that also doesn't match up with my GDB output. We are using x86 assembly.

EDIT: typos, and my getEsp function looks exactly like the other one:

```
getEsp:
    movl %esp, %eax
    ret
```

Comment: hi, it's been a long time since i dealed with assembler. but i remember i had once the same problem as you have. as far as i can remember the compiler added to the beginning of frame some extra info. (can be parameters of the function or some bytes for alligning or just some bullshit(VS does that on Windows)). i hope this hepls.

Comment: What compiler are you using? Some, like GCC allow inline assembly and setting C variables in it. So with GCC inline, you could do this without worrying about calling conventions. And, just so you know, C doesn't return things in `eax` by convention. I think it uses the stack.

Comment: what is the "esp" variable and how is it initialized?

Comment: Those printf statements can't print anything but strings -- you don't pass any variables to them.  Show us your ACTUAL CODE that you have written.

Comment: Sorry, forgot the variables in my printf.  I am using GCC, but we have to write assembly functions to get the pointers.  I also put the code to get esp. Thanks.

Comment: Check http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Return-Address.html - you can use `__builtin_frame_address(0)`. That'll give you the base of the current function's stackframe even if you've optimized framepointers out. If you compiled with framepointers, that'll just make the compiler emit the `movl %ebp, ...` / `movq %rbp, ...`. If you optimized them out, it'll give something like `lea ...(%esp), ...` / `lea ...(%rsp), ...`; agreed though that on framepointer-less code, there's not much you can do with the knowledge on where the frame starts.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. For reading a register, it's indeed best to use [GCC extended inline assembly syntax](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html).
2. Your `getEbp()` looks like it should work if you compiled it in a separate assembler file.
3. Your `getEsp()` is obviously incorrect since it doesn't take the return address pushed by the caller into account.

Here's a code snippet that gets `ebp` through extended inline asm and does stack unwinding by chasing the frame pointer:

```
struct stack_frame {
        struct stack_frame *prev;
        void *return_addr;
} __attribute__((packed));
typedef struct stack_frame stack_frame;

void backtrace_from_fp(void **buf, int size)
{
        int i;
        stack_frame *fp;

        __asm__("movl %%ebp, %[fp]" :  /* output */ [fp] "=r" (fp));

        for(i = 0; i < size && fp != NULL; fp = fp->prev, i++)
                buf[i] = fp->return_addr;
}
```

I'll show two working implementations of reading the registers below. The pure asm functions are `get_ebp()` and `get_esp()` in `getbp.S`. The other set implemented as inline functions are `get_esp_inline()` and `get_ebp_inline()` at the top of `test-getbp.c`.

In `getbp.S`

```
.section .text
/* obviously incurring the cost of a function call
   to read a register is inefficient */
.global get_ebp
get_ebp:
movl %ebp, %eax
ret

.global get_esp
get_esp:
/* 4: return address pushed by caller */
lea 4(%esp), %eax
ret
```

In `test-getbp.c`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

/* see http://sourceware.org/systemtap/wiki/UserSpaceProbeImplementation */
#include <sys/sdt.h>

int32_t *get_ebp(void);
int32_t *get_esp(void);

__attribute__((always_inline)) uintptr_t *get_ebp_inline(void)
{
    uintptr_t *r;
    __asm__ volatile ("movl %%ebp, %[r]" : /* output */ [r] "=r" (r));
    return r;
}

__attribute__((always_inline)) uintptr_t *get_esp_inline(void)
{
    uintptr_t *r;
    __asm__ volatile ("movl %%esp, %[r]" : /* output */ [r] "=r" (r));
    return r;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    uintptr_t *bp, *sp;

    /* allocate some random data on the stack just for fun */
    int a[10] = { 1, 3, 4, 9 };
    fprintf(fopen("/dev/null", "r"), "%d\n", a[3]);

    STAP_PROBE(getbp, getbp); /* a static probe is like a named breakpoint */
    bp = get_ebp();
    sp = get_esp();
    printf("asm: %p, %p\n", (void*)bp, (void*)sp);
    bp = get_ebp_inline();
    sp = get_esp_inline();
    printf("inline: %p, %p\n", (void*)bp, (void*)sp);
    return 0;
}
```

We can now write a GDB script to dump `ebp` and `esp` while making use of the `getbp` static probe defined in `test-getbp.c` above.

In `test-getbp.gdb`

```
file test-getbp

set breakpoint pending on
break -p getbp
commands
silent
printf "gdb: 0x%04x, 0x%04x\n", $ebp, $esp
continue
end

run
quit
```

To verify that the functions return the same data as GDB:

```
$ gdb -x test-getbp.gdb
< ... >
gdb: 0xffffc938, 0xffffc920
asm: 0xffffc938, 0xffffc920
inline: 0xffffc938, 0xffffc920
< ... >
```

Disassembling `test-getbp` `main()` produces:

```
   0x08048370 <+0>: push   %ebp
   0x08048371 <+1>: mov    %esp,%ebp
   0x08048373 <+3>: push   %ebx
   0x08048374 <+4>: and    $0xfffffff0,%esp
   0x08048377 <+7>: sub    $0x10,%esp
   0x0804837a <+10>:    movl   $0x8048584,0x4(%esp)
   0x08048382 <+18>:    movl   $0x8048586,(%esp)
   0x08048389 <+25>:    call   0x8048360 <fopen@plt>
   0x0804838e <+30>:    movl   $0x9,0x8(%esp)
   0x08048396 <+38>:    movl   $0x8048590,0x4(%esp)
   0x0804839e <+46>:    mov    %eax,(%esp)
   0x080483a1 <+49>:    call   0x8048350 <fprintf@plt>
   0x080483a6 <+54>:    nop
   0x080483a7 <+55>:    call   0x80484e4 <get_ebp>
   0x080483ac <+60>:    mov    %eax,%ebx
   0x080483ae <+62>:    call   0x80484e7 <get_esp>
   0x080483b3 <+67>:    mov    %ebx,0x4(%esp)
   0x080483b7 <+71>:    movl   $0x8048594,(%esp)
   0x080483be <+78>:    mov    %eax,0x8(%esp)
   0x080483c2 <+82>:    call   0x8048320 <printf@plt>
   0x080483c7 <+87>:    mov    %ebp,%eax
   0x080483c9 <+89>:    mov    %esp,%edx
   0x080483cb <+91>:    mov    %edx,0x8(%esp)
   0x080483cf <+95>:    mov    %eax,0x4(%esp)
   0x080483d3 <+99>:    movl   $0x80485a1,(%esp)
   0x080483da <+106>:   call   0x8048320 <printf@plt>
   0x080483df <+111>:   xor    %eax,%eax
   0x080483e1 <+113>:   mov    -0x4(%ebp),%ebx
   0x080483e4 <+116>:   leave  
   0x080483e5 <+117>:   ret
```

The `nop` at `<main+54>` is the static probe. See the code around the two `printf` calls for how the registers are read.

BTW, this loop in your code seems strange to me:

```
while( esp <= ebp )       
    esp -= 4;
```

Don't you mean

```
while (esp < ebp)
    esp +=4
```

?

Answer (score 5):

Because you're relying on implementation specific details, you need to provide more information about your target to get an accurate answer. You didn't specify architecture, compiler or operating system, which are really required to answer your question.

Making an educated guess based on the register names you referenced and the fact that you're using at&t syntax, I'm going to assume this is i386 and you're using gcc.

The simplest way to achieve this is using gcc variable attributes, you can try this, which is a gcc specific syntax to request a specific register.

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
     const uintptr_t register framep asm("ebp");

     fprintf(stderr, "val: %#x\n", framep);

     return 0;
 }
```

An alternative is to use inline assembly to load the value, like this:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    uintptr_t framep;

    asm("movl %%ebp, %0" : "=r" (framep));

    fprintf(stderr, "val: %#x\n", framep);

    return 0;
}
```

This requests a 32bit register for a write-operation (= modifier), and loads it onto framep. The compiler takes care of extracting the values you declare.

In gdb, you can print the value and verify it matches the output.

```
(gdb) b main
Breakpoint 1 at 0x40117f: file ebp2.c, line 8.
(gdb) r
Starting program: /home/zero/a.exe
[New Thread 4664.0x1290]
[New Thread 4664.0x13c4]

Breakpoint 1, main (argc=1, argv=0x28ac50) at ebp2.c:8
8           asm("movl %%ebp, %0" : "=r" (framep));
(gdb) n
10          fprintf(stderr, "val: %#x\n", framep);
(gdb) p/x framep
$1 = 0x28ac28
(gdb) p/x $ebp
$2 = 0x28ac28
(gdb) c
Continuing.
val: 0x28ac28
[Inferior 1 (process 4664) exited normally]
(gdb) q
```

Remember that you cannot rely on this behaviour, even on x86 gcc can be configured to not use the frame pointer and keeps track of stack usage manually. This is generally called FPO by Microsoft, or omit-frame-pointer on other platforms. This trick frees up another register for general purpose use, but makes debugging a little more complicated.

You're correct that eax is generally used for return values where possible in x86 calling conventions, I have no idea why the comments on your post claim the stack is used.