# Dumping stack after crash with gcc on Windows

Tags: c++, windows, gcc

I want to write a (or use existing) crash handler for my app. 
The problem I've with that is that I want it for Windows and gcc.

I deeply searched for such solution but there are only VS ones.

So far I've a `handler` registered with `SetUnhandledExceptionFilter`. 
According to my observations when `handler` is called, stack is 'limited' to my `handler` function + a few extra system functions.

Original stack seems to be above it (according to original `esp` and `ebp` stored in `EXCEPTION_POINTERS` passed to my `handler`).

I was trying to switch current `esp` and `ebp` to saved ones, but I usualy ends with crash.

I've also tried using posix' `signal` but stack is limited in the same way.

Comment: You haven't asked a question.

Comment: Isn't it obvious? I don't know how to dump stack in case of crash for windows app compiled with gcc.

Comment: The fact that you don't know something isn't a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I kept searching for the answer and here is what I've got:

there are (at least) two ways of finding real stack in case of application crash under windows.

1. stack can be backtraced with simple trick described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13438582/1749713). It is necessary to use `ebp` member from `EXCEPTION_POINTERS` instead of real `ebp` register.
2. `STACKFRAME64` example usage [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5705650/stackwalk64-on-windows-get-symbol-name)

Then it is necessary to convert addresses into function names. Here I've found 3 approaches:

1. `addr2line`
2. `SymFromAddr`
3. [`bfd`](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/bfd/index.html)

What's problematic - all these are working with particular executable file. It is necessary to handle extra dll files separately.

In my program I'll try to use KDE5's [`KCrash`](https://github.com/KDE/kcrash) + [`drkonqi`](https://github.com/KDE/plasma-workspace/tree/master/drkonqi). Both projects are source of valuable information by the way.